# Implementing logic and editing of existing SuiteCRM modules

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm pretty new to SuiteCRM and would like to extend the functionalities of existing Interfaces.
From my experience until now every interface (Contact, Accounts, ...) is basically a module.

Yet I couldn't figure out how to implement changes in the existing ones. Or how to download them as exportable Modules.

As an example: In the module `Accounts` I would like to add a button that downloads all selected Accounts as CSV-File.

If it's possible: How do I ensure the module-changes won't be reverted in the next update?

In case that's not possible: 
I was researching the correctly: The alternative approach would be setting up a Custom View with the usage of Custom Actions?

Comment: The ability to export a list of accounts is already there. From the Accounts list screen, select the ones you want, and then under "Bulk Action", select export.

Comment: You can edit modules and add functionality to them. Best practice is to do your edits in custom/modules/~ModuleName~ otherwise any changes made to the code will be overwritten when you do an upgrade. After you make any changes to the code, go to the repair screen in the admin and do a quick repair and rebuild.

Comment: @DigitalMcGrath - I was only choosing a random example which could help me to improve my SuiteCRM-Skills, I didn't know it existed already. But the question was towards the direction whether or not it's possible to make changes in the already included modules, NOT those which are custom-created.

Comment: It's very possible. Look in custom/modules/whatever module. If you need to edit a file that is not there, just copy it from modules/whatever module.

Comment: How is it possible to export a modified built-in module? And is it certain it will not be overwritten when an update is committed?

Comment: What do you mean by export? Are you referring to moving changes from development to production?

Comment: Moving the modified modules from one SuitCRM-Application to another

Comment: To my knowledge, the only way to "export" a module would be to build a custom module. That being said, you can just copy files from one installation to another if you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can export your customization right from studio.
Even if you have done customization in inbuilt module, you can go to studio -> select module -> Export Customization(Top Let corner).

Comment: Please don't use signatures; you can add links in your profile, if you want to.